# AMD 6600 xt -- daily - display corruption on Jammy

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

About once a day, usually on the lock screen I see lots of display corruption -- green matrix type looking things. When I'm in this state I can't always login, various apps exit.

What logs should I capture to debug this?

```
➜  ~ sudo lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'                        
[sudo] password for deem: 
2f:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M] (rev c7)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RX 6600 MECH 2X
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu

➜  ~ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
➜  ~ uname -a
Linux lahaina 6.0.1-060001-generic #202210120833 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Oct 12 08:37:06 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
➜  ~ 



➜  ~
```

Comment: Install the correct driver for the video card.

Comment: Glad to -- I didn't realize the default kernel one was not the correct one. Would appreciate a pointer to how to do this and now to confirm?

Comment: @David looks like the amdgpu driver is indeed being used, and that is the correct one. What do you suggest?